# Limit behavior near $\infty$ for continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. Define $f^* : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ by $f^*(s):=\max\{f(x): {0\le x\le s}\}$ for $s \in [0,\infty)$.

I'd like to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{f^*(s)}{s}=0$, provided $\displaystyle \lim_{s\to \infty}\frac{f(s)}{s}=0$. 
It seems true, but I cannot prove it.

Please let me know if you have any comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$, let $M>0$ be such that $f(s)/s<\epsilon$ for all $s>M$. For such a $s$, then $f^{\ast}(s)\leq\max\{f(x): 0\leq x\leq M\}+\color{red}\sup\{f(x): M<x\leq s\}$, then $f^{\ast}(s)/s\leq s^{-1}\max\{f(x): 0\leq x\leq M\}+\epsilon$, taking $s\rightarrow\infty$, then $\limsup_{s\rightarrow\infty}f^{\ast}(s)/s\leq\epsilon$, this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, then $\lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}f^{\ast}(s)/s=0$.

I think some steps need to be clarified: How's $\sup\{f(x): M<x\leq s\}/s\leq\epsilon?$

First, fix an $x\in(M,s]$, then $x>M$ and hence $f(x)/x<\epsilon$ by the choice of our $\epsilon>0$. Hence $f(x)<\epsilon x$. Since $x\leq s$, so $\epsilon x\leq\epsilon s$, so we have for every $x\in(M,s]$, $f(x)<\epsilon s$, hence taking supremum to all such $x$, we get $\sup\{f(x): M<x\leq s\}\leq\epsilon s$.

Comment: In third line, we need the extreme value theorem in order to prove it in detail.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, I can do it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want me to edit your answer? Or do you check if I understand your answer?

Comment: I think one should write $\sup$ instead of $\max$ for the term $\{f(x): M<x\leq s\}$, but in generally that doesn't hurt that much and I don't have really used EVT.

Comment: I understand your answer. Thanks again. By the way, we may use max instead of sup, if we choose M so that $f(s)/s<\epsilon$ for all $s \geq M.$

Comment: Yes, true, that would be more efficient, but then EVT takes place. Thanks for your reminding. Of course, EVT takes place all over this question because of the definition of $f^{\ast}$.